# How do I trigger the browser context menu on an element. (As if the user right-clicked)

Tags: javascript, contextmenu

I have the need to trigger the opening of the browser (IE, Firefox, Safari, etc) context-menu via javascript. The problem I am trying to solve, is when an overlaid element is right-clicked, the element below it shows its context menu. So if the top element is a label, when you right click, I need to show the context menu for the input element below.

I know how to keep the label's context menu from showing, but I don't know how to open a context menu arbitrarily.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If I was in your place, I wouldn't try to hack it this way. I'd probably want to understand why the context-menu of the input box is showing up instead of the label. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Sorry, just deleted it after reading the question.

Comment: You can see my plugin here: http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/ and try to right click on the "contents" of the text field. If I can't trigger the browser context menu, it makes this plugin's use somewhat limited.

Comment: ... well, I didn't notice a problem, so... what was the answer in then end?

Comment: Possible workaround: You could set CSS `pointer-events: none` on the overlay, so that mouse clicks will fall through to the element behind it. Unfortunately, this CSS will also affect all child elements. So if you want elements on top of the overlay to be clickable, then you'll need to put them in a separate sibling div to the overlay div, rather than a child of the overlay div. Hope I'm not too late!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of unfortunate news, but this is impossible to do with Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

I don't want to frustrate you, quite the contrary, especially because you answered my own question :)

I don't think that a browser's contect menu is accessible via an ordinary script on a web page.

If what you are asking for was actually doable, then the browser makers would possibly consider this a bug and remove this behavior. Cross-browser, this behavior is very unlikely to be available today.

Why don't you capture mouse events, and whenever the mouse is directly in the area of the element below that you want to show the context menu for, push the covering element below, otherwise back on top?

That is one possiblity I could think of, basically revealing/exposing the hidden element depending on mouse position. Like cutting a hole into the overlay.

Or why don't you make the text field transparent and put the overlay below the text field entirely?

If this does not work out technically, then at least you have a point in filing bugs or enhancements against the targeted browsers.

BTW it looks like the context menu actually works if the user right-clicks directly at the position of the caret, so this might be another loophole for you to consider.

Comment: All very good thoughts. I think on the new release I am going to add support for showing the label *below* the input element as this will solve the issue. It just means the wrapping element needs to provide the background color for the input element or textarea. Should work though!

Answer (score 2):

I have a possible solution that may suit your needs. It is not perfect yet, I have only done a few quick tests in a few browsers (Fox 3.6, IE7, IE8, Chrome 4, Safari 3 on xp) It will need to be tweaked and improved but its a start. Basically the idea is to remove the label on right-click mousedown so that the desired field is hit by the mouseup event and therefore fires up the context menu on the relevant field.

```
// Remove the contextmenu from "In-Field" Labels
base.$label.bind("contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
}); 

// Detect right click on "In-Field" label:
// hide label on mousedown so mouseup will target the field underneath.
base.$label.mousedown(function(e){          
    if ( e.which == 3 ){
        var elLbl = $(this); 
        elLbl.hide();
        var elFid = $(this).attr("for");
        // bind blur event to replace the label when we are done.
        $("#" + elFid ).bind("blur.infieldlabel",function(){                    
            elLbl.show();
            $("#" + elFid ).unbind("blur.infieldlabel");                    
        });             
        return false;
    }
});
```

The IE and Safari browsers experience a strange issue where you need to click in and out twice before the label will display again (something to do with event timing I think). You may be able to easily see why this is happening by looking at the code. Also noticed slight glitch sometimes in the fox after pasting into the field, on blur the label appeared for a split second when it should not. This should be a fairly simply thing to rectify if you decide to incorporate this method into your code.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following in the console:

```
document.oncontextmenu = reEnable
```

That will print to the console the following:

```
reEnable()
{
    return true;
}
```

Done, you can now use the context menu.

Answer (score -1):

You can make Your `label`/`span` element `contenteditable="true"` and handle any further actions with listeners. Making it `contenteditable` will enable normal, input-like contextmenu to show up on right click.

And if someone doesn't care for IE support:

```
pointer-events: none
```