# Programatically show default context menu from Chrome content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I'm trying to find a way to open the default context menu on a [X,Y] viewport position inside a Chrome extension (content script). Is it possible? How can I do it?

The thing is, I've handlers on `mouseup`, `mousemove` `mousedown` and `contextmenu` which inhibit context menu and do some magic (gestures) so it'd be nice if I could just open the default context menu if no gesture was detected in `mouseup`. (i.e. if there was just single RMB click.)

I'm actually trying to fix this neat looking extension https://github.com/RyutaKojima/simpleGestures for the Gtk+ version of Chrome where the context menu is shown on mouse down.

Without this ability I guess I'll have to do temporarily disable `mouse(up|down)` and `contextmenu` handlers and somehow ***simulate*** RMB click in `mouseup` (if I won't get stuck on another limitation).

Comment: See this quesion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241478/how-do-i-trigger-the-browser-context-menu-on-an-element-as-if-the-user-right-c, it seems it can't be achieve via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Context menu invocation is a "user gesture" (Chrome uses it to allow an extension access a set of otherwise restricted functionality like reading/writing of clipboard or DOM of the active page in case only `activetab` permission is given in the extension's manifest). Thus your only way out is to make an accompanying crossplatform native app that can send a rightclick mouse event. It will be installed separately and communicate with your extension via [Native Messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: Whoa. Thanks. That seems like a possible route. I think it'll be better to focus on implementing this https://crbug.com/28226 though. Dev on IRC said that simple function for displaying context menu could make it in.